# IF (YES) construction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What is the meaning of this construction:

```
If (YES) {
   //some code
}
```

I found some examples of this kind of usage and I really don't understand what is the meaning of this if (YES).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do anything per-se. It's probably a relic left over from when there was a condition in that place. When debugging it could be quicker to convert an expression to YES than to remove the if statement altogether. Alternatively the programmer could be experimenting toggling a particular block of code by manually switching between YES and NO while running tests.

Comment: It is not just left there, it is used in several places in the same file.

Comment: Thank you Jim, I like your answer most of all.

Answer (score 3):

Literally, it means the code is always executed.
Change the YES to NO, you get rid of the "some code".

For myself, I may use this kind of technical for debugging if my editor doesn't provide a function to toggle "comment/uncomment lines of code".

Answer (score 1):

The if condition always evaluates to true and 'some code' always executes.

The developer probably understood at the time of writing that there was need for a condition but that the condition was unknown at that time.

As Mr.pppoe says it's very easy to revisit and update the condition at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Its objective c. So YES is a boolean literal which is always true.

```
if (YES) {
// this code block is always executed. 
}
```

This is perhaps used for, teaching conditions to newbie programmers.

Answer (score 0):

YES is probably a [boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) variable.
and it means that if YES equal true then do what is inside the block.

```
bool YES = true;
if (YES) {cout << "inside cause YES is true";}
YES = false; 
if (YES) {cout << "not inside cause YES is false";}  // this will not be printed
```

Comment: We are talking about objective-c where YES/NO are boolean values which equals to TRUE/FALSE.